# Is villain masculine?

Tags: grammatical-gender

In India we generally use heroine as the female counterpart of a hero in a film. Is it grammatically acceptable? Further, is there any feminine counterpart for a villain either in tinsel world or in real life?

Comment: You have a plethora of choices, as *female villains* run the gamut from the grotesque [**Wicked Witch of the West**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicked_Witch_of_the_West) terrorizing the *Land of Oz* like a predator drone, to the banal (*and, perhaps, more frightening*) [**Nurse Ratched**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_Ratched), prosaic guardian of the status quo administering her bitter pills to the patients of the Salem, Oregon, State Hospital, in Ken Kesey's *One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest*.

Comment: @LittleEva Good choices - two of my 'favourites'. To the OP, yes *heroine* is a perfectly acceptable term, especially to anyone of my advanced age. The word *villain* usually covers both masculine and feminine cases (though *villainess* does exist). In French the words *villain (m)* and *villaine (f)* do not have the strength of meaning that *villain* has in English - they tend to translate as *naughty* e.g. with children.

Comment: Check-out these links: [**Does the term 'heroine' retain its legitimacy?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216145/does-the-term-heroine-retain-its-legitimacy-in-a-world-of-gender-equality); and: [**Is ‘hero’ applicable to females?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175162/is-hero-applicable-to-females/175163#175163).

Comment: As noted by Little Eva. The term "heroine" is not traditionally the counterpart of "hero" but rather the counterpart of "sidekick". That is, the heroine supports the hero but is not the main hero of the story. Therefore there is an increasing use of the term "hero" to refer to women in stories where there is no male hero (or ones where the hero/love-interest dynamic is inverted)

Answer (score 12):

**Villainess** is the feminine counterpart of the word, though it is rarely used. Most of the time in normal conversation, and Disney would prove as an example, villain can refer to both genders

Comment: [**Cruella de Vil**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruella_de_Vil)

Comment: _Cruella de Vil –  Little Eva_ just looks wrong, somehow.

Comment: Why? @Edwin Ashworth

Comment: The dash can signify an appositive.

Comment: Very clever, I misread your comment. Gotta remember to watch you more closely, @Edwin Ashworth.

Comment: You guys are funny :)

Comment: My wife says I'm witty about half the time. Or words to that effect.